# Sorting using comparator and crieria from map using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

Let's consider a java class `Parent` with 20 attributes (attrib1, attrib2 .. attrib20) and its corresponding getters and setters.

`List<Parent>` list contains n `Parent` objects.

Now I want to sort this list based on mutliple criteria. I will use comparator interface to build the sorting criteria.

The sorting arrtibutes are stored as a map.

```
Map< AttributeName, Ascending/Decending>
```

So I want to iterate through map and bulid comparator interface for each key.

How can we iterate through map and build comparator interface for each key and then connect these comparator interfaces.

I accept pure java 8 code to solve this problem.

Comment: maybe show us what you tried until now?

Comment: `Comparator<Parent> byFirst = (e1, e2) -> e2.getAttrib2().compareTo(e1.getAttrib2()); 
Comparator<Parent> bySecond = (e1, e2) -> e2.getAttrib12().compareTo(e1.getAttrib12());
Comparator<Parent> result = byFirst.thenComparing(bySecond);
Collections.sort(parenList,result);`

Comment: try to put this in your question and explain what didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use reflection, it's not possible to achieve this. Furthermore, if you don't use a `LinkedHashMap` or that the attributes' names are not chained in a lexicographical or an other defined order that ensure you chain them in the correct order, it'll be not possible to retrieve which one you want to chain first.

To be honest, using reflection for this seems more like a hack. I think you could improve your design.

What I suggest is to create a `LinkedHashMap<String, Comparator<Parent>> map = new HashMap<>();`(if you don't need the keys a `LinkedHashSet` might be sufficient), from there you insert the comparators in the order you want to chain them.

Then you're looking for a reduction. You iterate through the set of entries' value, and then you chain the comparator by reducing them:

```
Comparator<Parent> cmp = map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                            .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
                            .get(); //check also orElse, orElseThrow, etc.
```

If your `Map` is not a `LinkedHashMap` but that the keys can be compared to get the desired chain, you can sort the stream with `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())` for example.

You can either have a `Map<String, SimpleEntry<Comparator<Parent>, Boolean>>` if you want to store the logic ascending/descending, you'd just need to add another mapping operation:

```
...
.map(Map.Entry::getValue)
.map(e -> e.getValue() ? e.getKey().reversed() : e.getKey())
...
```

So an example of such a `Map` could be

```
Map<String, SimpleEntry<Comparator<Parent>, Boolean>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("id", new SimpleEntry<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Parent::getId), true));
map.put("name", new SimpleEntry<>(Comparator.comparing(Parent::getName), false));
```

Answer (score 0):

First I assume that your `Parent` class has the `get` method which can provide an attribute by its name. It can be implemented using reflection:

```
public class Parent {
    public Object get(String fieldName) {
        try {
            return getClass()
                .getMethod(
                   "get"+Character.toTitleCase(fieldName.charAt(0))+fieldName.substring(1))
                .invoke(this);
        } catch(IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException |
                NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Or probably using EJB introspection or other mechanism which is suitable in your case.

Having this we can define the following method:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
static Comparator<Parent> getComparator(Map<String, Boolean> sortOrder) {
    return sortOrder.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue() ? 
            Comparator.comparing(
                (Parent parent) -> (Comparable)parent.get(entry.getKey())) : 
            Comparator.comparing(
                (Parent parent) -> (Comparable)parent.get(entry.getKey())).reversed())
        .reduce((a, b) -> a.thenComparing(b))
        .orElse((a, b) -> 0);
}
```

Where `sortOrder` key is the field name and `sortOrder` value is `true` for ascending sort. I did not manage to implement it without `@SuppressWarnings`, but nevertheless it's Java 8 style as you wanted. The method can be used in this manner:

```
Map<String, Boolean> sortOrder = new LinkedHashMap<>();
sortOrder.put("a", true);
sortOrder.put("b", false);
persons.stream().sorted(getComparator(sortOrder)).forEach(System.out::println);
```